# Reading 4 byte integers from binary file in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a some sets of binary files (some are potentially large (100MB)) that contain 4 byte integers.

Can anyone supply a code snippet to show how to extract each 4 byte integer until the end of the file is reached? Using Python 2.7.

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use [`struct.unpack()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#struct.unpack):

```
with open(filename, 'rb') as fileobj:
    for chunk in iter(lambda: fileobj.read(4), ''):
        integer_value = struct.unpack('<I', chunk)[0]
```

This uses `<I` to interpret the bytes as little-endian unsigned integers. Adjust the format as needed; `>` for big-endian, `i` for signed integers.

If you need to read a lot of integer values in one go and know how many you need to read, take a look at the [`array` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html) as well:

```
from array import array

arr = array('L')
with open(filename, 'rb') as fileobj:
    arr.fromfile(fileobj, number_of_integers_to_read)
```

where you'd need to use [`array.byteswap()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html#array.array.byteswap) if the endianess of the file and your system didn't match:

```
if sys.byteorder != 'little':
    arr.byteswap()
```

Comment: +1 for `array.fromfile`. You could put it in a `while True:` loop inside `try: .fromfile.. except EOFError: pass` to avoid knowing `number_of_integers_to_read` before hand.

Comment: you can avoid the need for `number_of_integers_to_read` by reading from file to bytes stream `data=fileobj.read()` followed by a call to `arr.frombytes(data)`:

Comment: @AlexeyPolonsky: or you can use `arr.fromfile(fileobj, sys.maxsize)` and just catch the `EOFError` exception.

Comment: Use `struct.iter_unpack()' to load all numbers at once. You just need to read the entire file at once (if it can fit into your memory)

Answer (score 5):

Check out the NumPy [`fromfile` function](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromfile.html). You provide a simple type annotation about the data to be read, and the function efficiently reads it into a NumPy `ndarray` object.

```
import numpy as np
np.fromfile(file_name, dtype='<i4')
```

You can change `dtype` to reflect size and byte order as well. [See here for some examples.](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html)