# Convert a binary file into an array of integers directly in python?

Tags: python, list

I am trying to read binary file into a list of bytes. I was looking into this thread but it only gives me an array of characters.

[How do I convert string characters into a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10610158/how-do-i-convert-string-characters-into-a-list)

More or less what I want is this:

```
with open("decompressed_data.bin", mode='rb') as file:
    fileContent = file.read()
myStrList = list(fileContent)
# then convert this to a list of integers directly.
myIntList = convertToIntList(myStrList)
```

Is there a way to convert this list of characters into a list of integers without looping through every character?

Better yet, can I read the binary file direct into a  list of integers the Python way?

Comment: What python version? 2 or 3?

Comment: Does this help at all? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22229229/reading-4-byte-integers-from-binary-file-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python, you have the binascii module in the standard library.  For example:

> binascii.hexlify(*data*)

return the hexadecimal representation of the binary *data*. that is, each byte gets converted into a two-digit hex integer representation.  Does that help you out?

Comment: that will do it.

Answer (score 1):

Python 3s updated `open`, available as `io.open` in Python 2.7, will do this directly. Although it may be printed resembling a character string, the object returned by `read` on a binary file is a *bytes* object, which behaves as a sequence of integers. You can see this if you print the element at a particular index, or by noticing it yields ints when you iterate over it.